# How to achieve 3.5m distance between layers in a slime farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to this research video (skip to 4:30 ish)

it's far more efficient to have 3.5m distance between layers in your slime farm. However, slimes cannot spawn on slabs, so how should I achieve 3.5m distance?

The idea is to pack a few more layers by using slabs and having 3.5m distance, instead of 4m distance.

**And one more question:**

At what level should the first platform be? Slimes spawn on layers below 40, does that mean the first platform should be at 39 or 40?

Thanks!

**EDIT TO QUESTION #2**

According to wiki

> Slimes spawn in the Overworld in specific chunks below layer 40

Which should mean that layer 40 is not valid. I also set up a test platform at 40 and no spawns yet (sitting at 24 blocks from the edge of the platform). So I guess 39 is the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have slabs in the upper half of a block, or the lower half. Slimes (and other mobs) *will* spawn on top-half slabs. So, if you have three blocks of air, followed by a top-half slab, you end up with 3.5 blocks of air and a spawnable surface.

Also, of note - slimes spawn below level 40 in slime chunks AND in swamp biomes at any level, influenced by the phase of the moon. You can read more on the [slime wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime).

Comment: Slime spawning in Swamp biomes is only between level 51 and 68 or something like that.

Comment: Confirmed, I just had a slime spawn on a top slab :)

Comment: I have another concern though. I have to use jack'o lanters to light up the place and when the platform is only a slab thick, there will be pumpkins sticking from the bottom, which will make the ceiling just 3 blocks high. It kind of defeats the whole purpose :/